# How can I restrict access ActiveAdmin login page by ip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

**rails version**

rails 3.2.1

**Goal:**

Access ActiveAdmin login page only office computer.

**Code:**

route.rb

constraints(:ip => /(^127.0.0.1$)|(^192.168.10.[0-9]*$)/) do

```
 match 'admin/' => 'admin#login'
```

end

It is not work, any suesstion?

==========================

I edit my route.rb follow code

```
  constraints(:ip => /(^127.0.0.1$)|(^192.168.10.[0-9]*$)/) do
    ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  end
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
```

it's work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refer to Rails guides Chapter routing (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints):

```
class WhitelistConstraint
  def initialize
    @ips = Whitelist.retrieve_ips
  end
 
  def matches?(request)
    @ips.include?(request.remote_ip)
  end
end
 
TwitterClone::Application.routes.draw do
  match 'admin/' => 'admin#login',
    :constraints => WhitelistConstraint.new
end
```

I'm sure this can also be done using another way but I'm sure you get the point.

Comment: Thank your reply^^

I read Rails guides Chapter routing and edit route.rb

 constraints(:ip => /(^127.0.0.1$)|(^192.168.10.[0-9]*$)/) do
 ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
 end
 devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config

it's work,thank you!

Comment: Did this answer help you? If yes, I'd really appreciate if you mark my answer as accepted. Otherwise, please, tell me what you else need to know. :)

Answer (score 1):

I use this way, because you are able to move some logic out into a class if it is too complex for routes.

This class must have a matches? method defined on it which either returns true if the user should be given access to that route, or false if the user should not.

It helps me to add ips to the array without regex.

I hope, it helps someone)

More info - https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.2/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scoping.html#method-i-constraints

```
class WhitelistConstraint
  IPS = %w[
    143.132.200.43,
  ]

  def self.matches?(request)
    IPS.include?(request.remote_ip)
  end
end

Rails.application.routes.draw do

  constraints(WhitelistConstraint) do
    ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
    mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
  end
end
```